# is it correct to say "though" in this context

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I want to ask my manager something. i tried this

> I have some questions, though I do know that I have asked you a lot and I am so sorry for losing your time.

is though correct in this context?

Comment: There is more than one problem with that sentence, for example it is more common to say: "...I'm sorry for *wasting your time*."

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks for your correct. what about "though" ?

Comment: I would suggest first that you edit your sentence, change "losing" with "wasting" because users more competent than I will comment that there are stylistic issues. In my opinion, the position of *though* in the sentence is acceptable.

Comment: I know I've asked you so many already, but I have another question if you don't mind.
If you're not happy with a sentence, don't dwell too much on single words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wish to use the word though in that location in that sentence, you should prefix it with "even" to make the sentence flow better.

> I have some questions, even though I do know that I have asked you a lot and I am so sorry for losing your time.

However, the best way would be to rearrange the sentence.

> I know I may have asked you a lot of questions, and I hope I am not wasting your time, but I have some other questions to ask you, if that is okay.

Answer (score 1):

Start the sentence over. No need to keep the though in at all. I think it would sound better with a little rearrangement too.

> I know I have been asking a lot of questions and I am sorry for wasting your time, but I have a few more questions I would like to ask.